# SQLite verficar se dados ja esxiste

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Olá

Tenho uma aplicação onde ao fazer login se tiver conexão com a internet ela deve trazer os dados do web service e inserir no banco. Ai até ai tudo bem, porem minha duvida é a seguinte:

Ao fazer o login e receber os dados do usuario através de uma consulta no web service, quero verificar se este usuário já existe na minha tabela e fazer os seguintes procedimentos:

Caso exista, atualiza-lo.
Caso não exista, inseri-lo.

Abaixo segue meu codigo de inserção no banco.

```
  private SQLiteDatabase db;
private CriaBanco criaBanco;

public ProfessorDAO(Context context) {criaBanco = new CriaBanco(context);}

public String insereProfessor(Professor professor) {
    ContentValues valores;
    long resultado = 1;

    db = criaBanco.getWritableDatabase();
    valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("CODPROF", professor.getCodProfessor());
    valores.put("NOME", professor.getNomeProfessor());
    valores.put("USUARIO", professor.getUsuario());
    valores.put("SENHA", professor.getSenha());

    resultado = db.insertOrThrow("PROFESSOR", null, valores);
    db.close();

    if (resultado == -1)
        return "Erro de registro";
    else
        return "Registro Inserido com sucesso";

}
```

Comment: Você pode verificar se o banco está nulo, quando ele está vazio é retornado como **null**

Comment: Ok, mas e se ele estiver dados mas porem esses dados não estejam atualizados

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de usar

```
resultado = db.insertOrThrow("PROFESSOR", null, valores);
```

use

```
resultado = db.repalace("PROFESSOR", null, valores);
```

[replace](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#replace%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues%29) criará um novo registo ou actualizará um existente com a mesma chave primária<sup>(1)</sup>.

<sub><sup>(1)</sup> **"valores"** tem de conter a(s) coluna(s) referente(s) à chave primária da tabela *PROFESSOR*</sub>